# Can anyone help me find this case of a boy who died from an OR mistake during tonsillectomy?

Tags: surgery, death, reference-request, procedure-purposes, tonsil-tonsillectomy

I realize that this is obscure.

In the 1990s, I remember reading an article in either Time or Newsweek about how a hospital that screwed up a tonsillectomy, resulting in the death of their young patient, had quickly investigated, discovered, admitted, and took full responsibility to the patient's family of their mistake, which was an error in their operating room procedure.  The article was more about the new tack of the hospital in admitting fault right away, instead of stonewalling and forcing the victims to sue.

But I am more interested in the procedural mistake to use as an illustration in another issue.  As I recall, on the surgical tray, they had several liquids in little dishes, and a couple were completely colorless and clear that they were inadvertently swapped.  I think the boy was injected with something that was supposed to be anesthetic but the liquid was some kinda surgical solvent of some kind.  They injected the boy with the wrong stuff and the boy suddenly died and, for 48 hours, they did not know what they did wrong.

This, of course, precipitated a change in the OR protocol and this is what I want to focus on as an object lesson for another issue.

If anyone has **any** idea of the story and can point to it, I would be much obliged.

Similarly, if this story cannot be found, I would like it if someone can point me to a good, recent story of a common medical procedure gone fatally wrong. Ideally, the case is investigated and they discover the fatality was totally unnecessary because of a flawed procedure or protocol, own up to it, and then immediately correct the procedure.

I want a good example of that.

Comment: https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/os-xpm-1990-09-18-9009180487-story.html

Comment: This is an interesting story, @JohnP.  And I might use it.  And the year is approximately correct.  I don't think it's exactly the story I am looking for but I might use this.  --------  Thank you.

Comment: That part of your story where they had liquid in dishes doesn't make sense. You sure you've got that part right? Why would drugs be poured into unlabeled dishes? Maybe some other liquids such as betadine, but not drugs. And I can't imagine a nurse filling a syringe from an unlabeled dish of liquid. If it really happened that way the hospital had no choice but admit guilt and settle.

Comment: I know it doesn't seem right and I will confess that my memory may have messed up something.  It was some kind of array of containers I thought and they accidently swapped something.

Comment: I second @CareyGregory's comment, as I had the same thought. There's nothing (no clear liquid, and no drugs; those are kept on the cart) on the OR surgical tray that either a doctor or a nurse would draw into a syringe with the possible exception of sterile saline for irrigation (in a 50cc syringe), not injection, and an injection of which is extremely unlikely to 1) occur and 2) kill anyone. JohnP probably found you the right article, and you're misremembering the details. I do know of cases where things were swapped with catastrophic consequences, but not with a child/tonsillectomy.

Comment: That being said, I think the Orlando Sentinel has some of the details wrong, so beware of quoting it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse , i would **love** finding a really good well-documented case of a catastrophic consequence of something getting swapped because of an error in protocol.  Where they had to recognize that the procedure was inherently flawed and needed to be changed.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - a too common error is the injection of vincristine intrathecally. This happens everywhere. The specific case I remember is that an oncology patient was supposed to get an intrathecal chemo agent (methotrexate, iirc) and a IV agent (vincristine) ; both colorless drug ampules were on the tray, and a female resident at the Penn State Hershey Medical Center erroneoulsy gave the patient the vincristine intrathecally; The patient had an immediate reaction, which made the error easily identifiable, and soon died. They made her a scapegoat...

Comment: ...(I mean, yes, she made a horrible mistake, but residents are overworked, and they make mistakes; that's why they have to do residencies.) They kicked her out of the residency program, and from what I remember, she never practiced medicine again. A host of remedies have been proposed/implimented, but so far only one European nation has eliminated this error completely. But if you want a common one, non-catastrophic, look at wrong side surgery (or wrong site surgery).

Comment: There are a ton of errors leading to preventable deaths; it shouldn't be hard to find one. There are specific case reports of the vincristine errors, so that should be easy enough.

Comment: Just to point out, that Orlando Sentinel article doesn't appear to be accessible in Europe (probably due to gdpr non compliance) so it cannot be accessed by quite a section of potential readers